# Querying in Apache Solr across multicore

Tags: java, apache, solr, multicore, solrj

I have a multicore setup with two cores within Apache Solr 4.7. The cores are fairly similar, but have separate schemas. When I write a query I want to be able to query across both of these cores at the same time. I was wondering how I can do this and if it is at all possible.

I saw a few posts that suggested that I should join the 2 cores in a 3rd core and create a 3rd schema.xml but I want to avoid that.

I would appreciate it if you can share a sample query.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Solr is extremely fast. Is there a reason why you don't want to make two queries and then combine the results in your application code? Alternatively, if you have two cores with schema so similar that you want to query them at the same time, you may want to consider combining them and not having separate cores at all.

Answer (score 0):

If your schemas are compatible, you can use the collection parameter:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?collection=collection1,collection2&q=*:*
```

See: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#Distributed_Requests and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Advanced+Distributed+Request+Options